# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT into Customer 
(CustomerID, Forename, Surname, DOB, Address, Email)   
VALUES ('1', 'Steven’, ‘Halls’, ‘08/02/1992’, ‘%d-%m-%y’, ‘12 Lesnes Abbey SE7 8TX’, ‘stevenH@gmail.com');
```

Could someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: What's this - `‘%d-%m-%y’`? it seems an extra value

Comment: Um...you specified 6 columns for insertion, but you gave data for seven columns.

Comment: Also, you are using curly quotes for some of your data instead of single quotes.  This won't work properly.

Comment: I don' need the %d-%m-%y?

Comment: so why is it there? remove it. Or was it a question? you are asking us if you need it?

Comment: Still not working when removed

Comment: Did you change all curly quotes to single like Tim suggested?

Comment: ' is the single quote, isn't it?

Comment: `Column count doesn't match value count`. That error message is very clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove ‘%d-%m-%y’ from insert statement, define DOB data type as Date.

You can't change the default format for a date during the table definition stage. (It must always obey the DATETIME, DATE or TIMESTAMP formats.) As the manual puts it:

See the [date and time reference docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) for more info.

As such, you'll have to use the [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function at the point of output to achieve this goal.

```
INSERT into Customer 
(CustomerID, Forename, Surname, DOB, Address, Email)   
VALUES ('1', 'Steven’, ‘Halls’, ‘1992-02-08’, ‘12 Lesnes Abbey SE7 8TX’, ‘stevenH@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for this help